# Flutter: low performance when zoom custom painter

Tags: performance, flutter

I'm try paint many TextSpan on custom painter. Everything ok, but when I try zoom painter it's become very slow. What's way to speed up?

Scale widget with custom paint:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return GestureTransformable(
    size: sz,
    initialScale: 0.3,
    maxScale: 40.0,
    minScale: 0.01,
    boundaryRect: Rect.fromLTWH(
      -sz.width * 10 / 2,
      -sz.height * 10 / 2,
      sz.width * 10,
      sz.height * 10,
    ),
    child: RepaintBoundary(
      child: CustomPaint(
        painter: CustomPaintSpans(),
      ),
    )
 );
}
```

and custom painter:

```
@override
void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {

double delta = 10.0;
double pixelSize = 10.0;

for (int j = 0; j < 100; ++j) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {

    double startX = delta + i * (pixelSize + 1);
    double startY = delta + j * (pixelSize + 1);

    ////////
    TextSpan textSpan = new TextSpan(
        text: "$i",
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 1, color: Colors.grey, fontWeight: FontWeight.w800));
    TextPainter tp = TextPainter(
        textScaleFactor: 10,
        text: textSpan,
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        textDirection: TextDirection.ltr);
    tp.layout();
    Offset offset;
    offset = Offset(startX - pixelSize * 0.5, startY - pixelSize * 0.5);
    tp.paint(canvas, offset);
    ///////////
  }
}
```

[performance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/190vD.png)
[app screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84xTy.jpg)

Comment: In shouldRepaint I return false.

Comment: creating 10000 `TextSpan`s and 10000 `TextPainter`s per frame is the bottleneck

Comment: Yes. But move painter is 60 fps, only zoom(scale) slow.

Comment: Yes, but I need this objects to paint.

Comment: what exactly do you have to paint?

Comment: I create application "color by number". I need paint many rects and inside rect paint number.

Comment: how many different numbers? 10000? from 0..9999?

Comment: Maybe from 0..40 but many rects with number inside. Total rects about 10.000.

Comment: so create only those 40 TextSpans / TextPainters, not 10000

Comment: When I zoom out I need show all rects it's about 10.000. Do you understand me? It's a game (colors by number).

Comment: Yes I understand you. Imagine that you broke the picture into 10,000 pieces and numbered them. How to show the whole numbered picture on the screen?

Comment: And zoom this picture?

Comment: I can move this picture with 60 fps but not zoom(scale).

Comment: because you are creating too much `TextSpan`s / `TextPainter`s

Comment: Now I don't understand. How create 40 numbers and show all picture with 10.000 numbers?

Comment: in your current code you are using only 100 different `TextPainter`s (for texts "0".."99") so do not create them inside two loops but instead pre-create those painters and store in some list

Comment: Thank you for idea. But unfortunately problem is that I call tp.paint in loop and low performance is still slow.

Comment: try this: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/nD6wGcCQBH/

Comment: Thank you for example. Your solution is very good. But in my phone (xiaomi redmi 6) is still trouble with performance. Maybe we can get image from picture and paint image instead picture in some case of scale?

Comment: try it, you will see pixels though when scaling